# App Pool creating multiple Sessions for each request? How to kill IIS Sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, application-pool, worker-process

We working for online travels website using asp.net for that we will have more users , for every request IIS ( We are using IIS8 ) creating one new session and that not killing even the webpage closed , that causes me performance degrade of application and more memory utilization process .

How can i kill sessions in IIS  and reduces memory optimization process .

Comment: You should seek the answer to why multiple Sessions are created, not try to kill them.

Comment: @Alexander Can you have an idea causing this ?

Comment: I'd have to see your application and code. I've once seen it happen when somebody created a "master page" as HTML, loading ASPX-Pages in Frames. That caused ASP.NET 1.1 to create on Session for each Frame...

Comment: Where do you save the session? InProc? Then, how long is your session timeout? What is your application pool recycling time?

Comment: default application pool recycling time 1740 min will be same @Hatjhie

Comment: saving Session By default InProc only @Hatjhie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this. Please reduce your app pool recycling time from 1740 minutes to maybe 60 minutes or 30 minutes.

Session would be cleared once the app pool recycled if you are using default session stored mode which is InProc.

Hope it helps. Thanks